# How to combile webpack with an external package.json script

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have two different scripts on my package.json one being

```
"start": "json-server server/index.js --routes server/routes.json --middlewares server/handle-delay.js server/handle-ads.js ",
```

and the other

```
"bw": "webpack --watch",
```

I wish to run both of these at the same time in my cli.

I have already resorted to running the codes as such

```
"start": "json-server server/index.js --routes server/routes.json --middlewares server/handle-delay.js server/handle-ads.js & bw ",
```

and also

```
"start": "json-server server/index.js --routes server/routes.json --middlewares server/handle-delay.js server/handle-ads.js webpack ",
```

and have received multiple errors

In finality I wish the code to run as a single command altogether.

Comment: I suppose you could create a script.sh which launches the 2 commands in background, you fetch their pid, and the script must wait the 2 pids to stop. By using `trap` to catch signals, you should kill both pid to ensure that killing this script will stop the 2 commands. You need to use bash `$?`, `trap`, and `wait`. To launch a command in background, you have to use `command &` and to get the pid use `PID_CMD1=$?` just after

Comment: I've used concurrently for this sort of thing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Answer (score 1):

Using a package called [concurrently](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently)

I was able to change the code to

```
"start": "concurrently  \"webpack -d -w\" \"json-server server/index.js --routes server/routes.json --middlewares server/handle-delay.js server/handle-ads.js\"",
```

which runs both commands at the same time smoothly. 
thanks to the author.

Answer (score 0):

Bash version (run_server.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ev

# the commands to launch
CMD1=./cmd1.sh # replace with your 1st command
CMD2=./cmd1.sh # replace with your 2nd command
# the logs output
LOG_CMD1=./log1.txt
LOG_CMD2=./log2.txt

# launch cmd 1
$CMD1 > $LOG_CMD1 2>&1 &
PID_CMD1=$!

# launch cmd2
$CMD2 > $LOG_CMD2 2>&1 &
PID_CMD2=$!

# register to some exit signals: Ctrl-C ...
trap "if kill -0 $PID_CMD1 > /dev/null 2>&1; then kill $PID_CMD1 $PID_CMD2; fi && wait $PID_CMD1 && wait $PID_CMD2" SIGINT TERM EXIT SIGKILL

# wait commands to end
wait $PID_CMD1
wait $PID_CMD2
```

The script starts the 2 commands in background, store the PIDs, and wait for the 2 scripts to stop.

If you kill this script, it will kill the subcommands as well.

Output should be forwarded in log files because you won't be able to understand which process write the output in the terminal.